# What are all the rune bonuses?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

When you kill a captain or a warchief, the level of the rune can get bonuses based on who and/or how you killed. What are those bonuses?

[image: Rune bonuses]

Comment: Are you seriously asking for a complete list of these bonuses?

Comment: I am; it is a finite list, and it's not particularly large. There is an achievement to get a level 25 rune, so it's useful.

Comment: You're assuming there's a pre-determined list of runes and that they're not algorithmically generated at run-time. From what I've seen in the game there's a wide variation in what can drop with a lot of randomization, making a "finite" list unrealistic to enumerate.

Comment: I'm not looking for a list of runes. I am looking for a list of the bonuses you can get to the level of a rune, as seen in the screenshot.

Comment: oooooh, I read that as the level of the stat bonuses in the rune, not the level of the rune itself, sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get up to a +6 bonus on a rune drop. It adds up as follows:

- +1 for Death Threat
- +1 for Knowing Weaknesses
- +1 for Exploiting Fear/Hate
- +1 for Revenge
- +2 for Warchief

And yes this means that you can get a level 26 rune. Though I'm not sure if that would trigger the achievement or not.

Comment: It may be possible but in my experience, you'll never get a level 26 rune - you will get epics. You will get lots of epics. You will pray for the epics to end.

Comment: Yep. There is that.

Comment: @IanPugsley, I have recieved L26 runes.  They give the same bonuses as their L25 cousins but "go one higher".